# Initialize data with init() call or ng-init?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS app, I have to init some values onload.

I wrote a function `init()` in this mind.

```
function init() {
    this.var = 'example';
}
```

Is it *better* to call `init` function at the end of my JS script, or with the `ng-init` attribute?

**Solution 1**

```
/* script.js */
function init() { /* instructions */ }
init();
```

**Solution 2**

```
/* script.js */
function init(){ // instructions // }}
// Not calling init() here

<!-- file.html -->
<div ng-controller="exampleCtrl as example" ng-init="example.init()">
```

Comment: solution 1 is better than with `ng-init`

Comment: Can you explain **why** ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit . you can see it in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`ngInit` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> This directive can be abused **to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates**. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these
>   few cases, **you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope**.

So when you have the choice, always prefer to initialize in your controller: Solution 1 is better.

---

More broadly, in terms of [separation of concerns](http://staydecent.ca/code/angular-js-separation-of-concerns/), I would advice to write the logic in your controller. If you have a common part of code used by several controllers, move it to a service. This will greatly simplify the maintainability of your application when growing up.

Answer (score 1):

If this is going to initialise some values ready for a page using them, you'd be using a controller, correct? So use the built in method for this called [$onInit()](https://toddmotto.com/on-init-require-object-syntax-angular-component/) ...

```
$onInit() {
  $scope.foo = 'some value';
  // Initialise other variables;
}
```

The [$onInit()](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#oninit) was added in AngularJS 1.5 for component controllers, but it works with all controllers.